# Installing gdcm on CentOS

Tags: centos, cmake

I am using CentOS 7.

I went to [the gdcm source page](http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Source) and the only Linux distros that it had a link for were Debian and Ubuntu.  I downloaded, and unzipped, GDCM-$VERSION-Linux.tar.gz.  I then read INSTALL.txt.  It gave the following istructions for installing gdcm.

```
 * git clone --branch release git://git.code.sf.net/p/gdcm/gdcm
 * mkdir gdcmbin
 * cd gdcmbin
 * ccmake ../gdcm
   [select your configuration]
 * Press 'c' (configure), Press 'g' (generate)
 * make
```

When I tried ccmake ../gdcm and pressed 'c' I got

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.9.2 or higher is required.  You are running version 2.8.12.2
```

I then tried

```
sudo yum install cmake
```

and got

```
Package cmake-2.8.12.2-2.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the needed version of `cmake`:

```
yum install cmake3
```

That will give you the tools: `cmake3` and `ccmake3`.
After that:

```
ccmake3 ../gdcm
```